# How do I get Batman Riddler trophies blocked by Catwoman gates?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

A couple of times now (once in the Museum area) I saw a Batman and Catwoman trophy both blocked by a grate in the ceiling that Catwoman can go through.  I haven't been past these gates as Catwoman yet, but I assume that she can't pick up the Batman trophy.

How do I get Batman past these gates?  Is there some gadget that can interact with it, or am I supposed to find another way around?

Comment: Not sure which gates you're referring to, but Catwoman _can_ pick up green trophies (assuming she can reach them, they often require Batman's gadgets). But of course, all green trophies can be reached with only Batman, too.

Comment: @hammar, the gates are square and kind of orange colored.  They're in the ceiling, in spots where Catwoman can jump up and grab the ceiling.  Does that help narrow it down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're talking about the one in the room with the water. That one's actually *above* the grates, so Catwoman cannot reach it.

You can get it with Batman by climbing up the scaffolding on the right side of the room and using the line launcher. You'll need to aim for the left side and then change direction when you're above the middle of the room.

Comment: There's also one in the hallway before the colisseum; you get to that one by grappling up on a beam and then line launching over.